# Vibration at 2000rpm (approx. 40 MPH) in 2004 Honda CR-V EX

Tags: honda, vibration, rpm, crv

Just recently, my Honda CR-V vibrates at 2000rpm/about 40MPH then stops when it's about 55-60+ MPH. Is this a big problem or can this be fixed? Thank you.

Comment: More than likely you threw a wheel weight. First stop is the tire shop to get your wheels rebalanced (get them checked, anyway).

Comment: Did you try what Paul recommended?

Comment: Not yet, may do it next week. Drove it today and it didn't seem to be there anymore. I'm going to drive it the rest of this week and see if I should take it in or not.